# How can the Bokeh Image node be used?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

From [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.64/Compositing_Nodes#Bokeh_Image):

> With the Bokeh Image node you can generate a reference image for blurs.

What are some example uses for this node?

Comment: it's designed to be plugged into the Bokeh Blur node in the "Bokeh" slot.

Comment: related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/bokeh-from-horizontal-to-vertical/74533#74533

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bokeh Image controls the shape of the out-of-focus area for the Bokeh blur node.

Generally, octagonal and circular shapes are very common for most camera lenses. If no bokeh image is supplied, then a circular bokeh is assumed.

[image: Bokeh Image]

Comment: Another application is to feed the bokeh shape with an animated "Mask" node, this lets you change the bokeh shape over time in a more radical way. Imagine drawing animal shapes running or love hearts rotating.

Answer (score -1):

bokeh is lens blur. the fun thing about it though is how the cameras aperture changes the shape of points of illumination to mimic that of the camera. of course blender doesnt have a real camera so we have to fake the effect. it can be done in the lense settings but it is often more convienient to  use the nodes.

take a look at these video lessons i made recently on this topic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqwmicmIxXA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PE_XdMID89o

Comment: Please add at least a brief explanation of how to do it. The answer should be valid on its own, and even if you made the video yourself, the link may go down, in which case this answer will be useless.