# Bokeh - From Horizontal to Vertical

Tags: camera, blur, depth-of-field

Hi guys I want my camera to display vertical bokeh stretch instead of horizontal. The rotation option in DOF settings of camera, doesnt rotate the bokeh.

Horizontal stretched bokeh (low res render just to illustrate)

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Maybe there is a simple solution to rotate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simulate the ellipsoidal [bokeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) created by [anamporphic lenses](http://www.red.com/learn/red-101/anamorphic-lenses) by changing the **ratio** on the depth of field settings.

The defalut value for ratio of **1:1 will give you a circular shape**, while a larger or smaller number will make the defocused elements deform in an ellipsoidal shape.

A value **higher than 1** will deform the defocused areas on **vertical** ellipsoids (the most common anamorphic lenses will compress the image on a 2:1 aspect)

Conversely to deform **horizontally** use numbers **smaller than 1**

[image]

[image]

To create custom shapes for the bokeh (As described in this link: http://www.diyphotography.net/can-you-make-computerized-shaped-bokeh/):

Create a plane with a hole that has the shape of the bokeh you want.

Place the plane really close in front of the camera (adjust the clipping distance if necessary, so that the camera can see the object)..

Set the depth of field on the camera, and render.

[image]

Click on the image to enlarge

[image]

Click on the image to enlarge

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! This is my try, would you have any criticism or feedback? I see the plane adds less contrast but I guess the cut outs that photographers use also add similar defects. I guess color correction and glow in post could help the realism in an actual project [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhBGD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhBGD.jpg) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BClaA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BClaA.png)

Comment: @TmkDigital keep in mind that when dealing with depth of field the same rules apply as they would on a real camera, the selective de-focus will be more evident on longer lenses and if the subjects are close to the camera. You might want to work with a camera with a large sensor size and also increase the length of your lens. One more think to remember is  you need to increase the number samples to get cleaner images.