# Create the circular distorion from an anamorphic lense

Tags: camera

I try to recreate the circular distortion of an anamorpic lense
like here

[image]

[image]

I know about this way to strech the bokeh vertically.
[Bokeh - From Horizontal to Vertical](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/bokeh-from-horizontal-to-vertical)

and i have seen this one were a fisheye lense is used.
https://code.blender.org/2014/08/anamorphic-bokeh/

and im using a lens distortion node in the compositor to achive additional realism.
Is there a way to create this circular distortion in the bokeh without a fisheye camera?

Comment: This was an inspiring question for me to come across. I spent a darn long time trying these aperture methods without liking the results. This past week i released what i think is your solution, buddy. Four some years later. So sorry i didn't think of this sooner. https://www.blendermarket.com/products/jackimorphic-camera-pack-v1 -jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use radial blur to simulate the effect of lens aberration in post-processing.

But the effect is also surprisingly easy to achieve in Cycles with the camera. Just add a black, circular aperture object in front of the camera:

[image]

[image]

Here is the setup from the camera's perspective. The more closed off the circle is, the heavier the vignetting:
[image]

[Blend file Download](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48930)

Comment: I dont get this to work somehow. Do you let the camera clip through the object or not ?

Comment: Added more detail to the answer, hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the Blendfile. It works. :))) But you have to put the aperture really close to the camera