# Custom Bokeh Shapes

Tags: camera, depth-of-field

I'm trying to make a Bokeh background like this:[image]

I've got the Bokeh in blender with a particle system copying a sphere that has an emission modifier. I'm using the depth of field to blur out the spheres. This creates a simple bokeh effect. I can increase the blade value to get triangles, squares, pentagons, etc. but that doesn't get complex shapes. in a normal camera, i'd put a piece of card with a shaped hole in it to make that shape appear on all the bokeh. That doesn't seem to work in blender. here is my attempt with a cross.[image]
And here is the render.
[image]
As you can see, this method doesn't work. What does?

Comment: Yes you can do it. Here is a tutorial, sorry I don't have time to write the answer up https://vimeo.com/28353103 The aperture shape must be at the right distance to the lens and the camera clipping needs to accommodate the distance to the lamp

Comment: You can make it work with a shape in frot of the lens. Make the shape smaller. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/bokeh-from-horizontal-to-vertical/74533?r=SearchResults#74533

Comment: Although this method is useful from an educational point of view, it's not the more efficient. You can do it in compositing with the Bokeh Blur node associated with a Bokeh Image node ( https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/bokeh_blur.html )

Answer (score 0):

To make it perfect, but your method is almost perfect. You have to move the bokeh shape closer to the camera and reduce it's size until the hole is smaller than the camera.